# Execute multiple SQL commands in one round trip

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, data-access

I am building an application and I want to batch multiple queries into a single round-trip to the database.  For example, lets say a single page needs to display a list of users, a list of groups and a list of permissions.

So I have stored procs (or just simple sql commands like "select * from Users"), and I want to execute three of them.   However, to populate this one page I have to make 3 round trips.

Now I could write a single stored proc ("getUsersTeamsAndPermissions") or execute a single SQL command "select * from Users;exec getTeams;select * from Permissions".

But I was wondering if there was a better way to specify to do 3 operations in a single round trip.  Benefits include being easier to unit test, and allowing the database engine to parrallelize the queries.

I'm using C# 3.5 and SQL Server 2008.

Comment: If this is ASP.Net, and the DB server is right next to the Web Server(or it is an internal only application), then this is most likely a premature optimization..

Comment: @Earlz, either a premature optimization or a fix for some other design problem.

Comment: Every time I come back and read this question I am amused at how many people read my simple example I made up for this question and assume they know the performance characteristics of my application better than I do.

Comment: Please read my answer under here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49687720/538387

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The single multi-part command and the stored procedure options that you mention are the two options.  You can't do them in such a way that they are "parallelized" on the db.  However, both of those options does result in a *single round trip*, so you're good there.  There's no way to send them more efficiently.  In sql server 2005 onwards, a multi-part command that is fully parameterized is very efficient.

**Edit**:  adding information on why cram into a single call.

Although you don't want to care too much about reducing calls, there *can* be legitimate reasons for this.

- I once was limited to a crummy ODBC driver against a mainframe, and there was a 1.2 second overhead on each call!  I'm serious.  There were times when I crammed a little *extra* into my db calls.  Not pretty.
- You also might find yourself in a situation where you have to configure your sql queries somewhere, and you can't just make 3 calls: it has to be one.  It shouldn't be that way, bad design, but it is.  You do what you gotta do!
- Sometimes of course it can be very good to encapsulate multiple steps in a stored procedure.  Usually not for saving round trips though, but for tighter transactions, getting ID for new records, constraining for permissions, providing encapsulation, blah blah blah.

Comment: single round-trip is the most important consideration anyways.

Answer (score 38):

Something like [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Database-ADO.net/ExecutemultipleSQLstatementsusingaSqlCommandobject.htm). The example is probably not very good as it doesn't properly dispose objects but you get the idea. Here's a cleaned up version:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    connection.Open();
    command.CommandText = "select id from test1; select id from test2";
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        do
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader.GetInt32(0));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("--next command--");
        } while (reader.NextResult());

    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for nice code example.  This is what I was talking about in the question with multiple sql statements in a single command.

Comment: Thanks for this, been looking for the proper way of handling connections and commands :)

Answer (score 2):

Making one round-trip vs three will be more eficient indeed. The question is wether it is worth the trouble. The entire ADO.Net and C# 3.5 toolset and framework opposes what you try to do. TableAdapters, Linq2SQL, EF, all these like to deal with simple one-call==one-resultset semantics. So you may loose some serious productivity by trying to beat the Framework into submission.

I would say that unless you have some serious measurements showing that you need to reduce the number of roundtrips, abstain. If you *do* end up requiring this, then use a stored procedure to at least give an API kind of semantics.

But if your query really is what you posted (ie. select *all* users, *all* teams and *all* permissions) then you obviosuly have much bigger fish to fry before reducing the round-trips... reduce the resultsets first.

Comment: I made those up off the top of my head.

Comment: +1 for telling me not to bother though.  Trust me, I'll be doing a lot of other things before I start doing this as the web server and database server are pretty close to each other.

Comment: But I think MSTF should implement some object (maybe there should be an IDisposable property in the ObjectContext that when entered, will execute all accumulated queries at once, setting each reslultset strongly-typed.

Answer (score 1):

I this [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896325.aspx) link might be helpful.

Consider using at least the same connection-openning; according to what it says [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx), openning a connection is almost the top-leader of performance cost in Entity-Framework.

Comment: Connection pooling will almost always ensure you only open one physical connection, so normally you don't need to worry about the performance cost of opening multiple connections.

Answer (score 0):

Build a temp-table? Insert all results into the temp table and then `select * from @temp-table`

as in,

```
@temptable=....
select @temptable.field=mytable.field from mytable
select @temptable.field2=mytable2.field2 from mytable2
```

etc... Only one trip to the database, though I'm not sure it is actually more efficient.

Comment: that would make 4 round trips ;)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, 3 round trips isn't really a big deal.  If you were talking about ***300*** round trips then that would be another matter, but for just 3 round trips I would conderer this to definitley be a case of premature optimisation.

That said, the way I'd do this would probably be to executed the 3 stored procuedres using SQL:

```
exec dbo.p_myproc_1 @param_1 = @in_param_1, @param_2 = @in_param_2
exec dbo.p_myproc_2
exec dbo.p_myproc_3
```

You can then iterate through the returned results sets as you would if you directly executed multiple rowsets.