# Is this an exact query?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have two tables

```
Inbox(id,accountid,emailfrom,emailsubject,emailbody,emaildate,attachment)
Trash(as above)
```

When a user wants to delete a row from the `inboxDataGridView`, first that row is copied to the `trash` table. I'm trying this query to copy the row first:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Trash(inboxid, accountid, emailfrom, subject, emailbody,emaildate,attachment) SELECT inboxid, accountid, emailfrom, subject, emailbody,emaildate,attachment FROM Inbox WHERE(inboxid = " + accountinfo.PEmailId + ")";(where accountinfo.PEmailId = selectedRow value
```

but this query gives me an error.

Kindly guide me on how I can do it, copy and remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

Insert:

```
INSERT INTO Trash(id, accountid, emailfrom, subject, emailbody,
   emaildate,attachment)
SELECT id, accountid, emailfrom, subject, emailbody,emaildate,attachment 
FROM Inbox 
WHERE id = @id
```

Delete:

```
DELETE Inbox
WHERE id = @id
```

You need to execute the statements, either [in the same command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336362/execute-multiple-sql-commands-in-one-round-trip) or as two separate commands [within a transaction](http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/transactions.html) depending on if you want to perform something else inbetween. The @id parameter should be provided as a command parameter in order to [prevent SQL injection attacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163917.aspx).

If you want part of the solution on the database side, you could either create this as a stored procedure or [as @ThitLwinOo suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9077380/66849) create a trigger. In case you're using the trigger approach, the Delete statement is enough to execute from your program.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is simple and better way to complete what you want is by writing trigger on delection. What is ur DB? SQL Server?

I assume your DB is Sql Server.. Plese try the following trigger in ur db.

---

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tri_BACKUP_DELETED_ROWS] 

ON [dbo].[Inbox]

AFTER DELETE

AS 

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
    BEGIN
        -- keep old record
        INSERT INTO Trash(inboxid, accountid, emailfrom, subject, emailbody,emaildate,attachment)       
        SELECT inboxid, accountid, emailfrom, subject, emailbody,emaildate,attachment 
        FROM DELETED
    END

END
```

---